# Jquery Mobile Multiple Select List disabled option not working when using .attr("disabled",true) in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to write some jquery code that will disable an option in a multiple select list when I choose a value from another select list. The code will add the disabled attribute to the select multiple list but it is not actually graying out the option. I have noticed that for it to actually disable the option in jquery mobile I have to add the class .ui-state-disabled to the unordered list li tag. I am not sure how I can achieve this though.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Elite CTA Create Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/themes/Estimates.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-form1", function() {
        $("select").each(function(idx) {
            $(this).change(function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                if($(this).attr("id") == "Priority")
                    linkOptions(value);
            });
        });

        $("#lead").change(function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $("#notify option[value='"+value+"']").attr("disabled",true);
                $("#notify").trigger("change");
        });
    });


    function linkOptions(priority) {
        var cases = {

            "Normal": {
                "commETA": "2 Days",
                "compETA": "1 Week"
            },
            "High": {
                "commETA": "Today",
                "compETA": "2 Days"
            },
            "Severe": {
                "commETA": "Today",
                "compETA": "Today"
            },
            "Emergency": {
                "commETA": "1 Hour",
                "compETA": "Today"
            }
        };

        if (cases[priority]) {
            $.each(cases[priority], function(key, value) {
                $("#" + key).val(value).trigger("change");
            });
        }               
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page-form1" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false">
        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel">
            <a href="index.php" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-left" data-ajax="false">View CTA's</a>
            <a href="create.php" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left" data-ajax="false">Create a CTA</a>
        </div> 
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <a href="#myPanel" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline"></a>
            <h1>Elite CTA Form</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="page-content1" data-theme="a">
            <form class="form-signin" id="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $formaction; ?>">
                <h4 class="form-signin-heading" style="text-align: center;">Please describe CTA Below</h4>

                <label style="font-weight: bold;">Customer Name:</label>
                <input name="Customer_Name" id="Customer_Name" type="text" class="form-control" autofocus required="required"><br />
                <label style="font-weight: bold;">Priority Level:</label>   
                <!-- Selected Priority Level will change the Time for Action and Completion Field Automatically JS Above -->
                <select name="Priority" id="Priority" class="selectnoreset" required>
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                    <option value="High">High</option>
                    <option value="Severe">Severe</option>
                    <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                </select><br />
                <label style="font-weight: bold;">Project:</label>
                <input name="Project" id="Project" type="text" class="form-control"><br />
                <label style="font-weight: bold;">Expected Time for Action:</label>
                <select name="commETA" id="commETA" class="selectnoreset" required>
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    <option value="1 Hour">1 Hour</option>
                    <option value="Today">Today</option>
                    <option value="2 Days">2 Days</option>
                    <option value="1 Week">1 Week</option>
                    <option value="2 Weeks">2 Weeks</option>
                </select><br />
                <label style="font-weight: bold;">Expected Time for Completion:</label>
                <select name="compETA" id="compETA" class="selectnoreset" required>
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    <option value="Today">Today</option>
                    <option value="2 Days">2 Days</option>
                    <option value="1 Week">1 Week</option>
                    <option value="2 Weeks">2 Weeks</option>
                    <option value="1 Month">1 Month</option>
                    <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
                </select><br />
                <label style="font-weight: bold;">Description of Issue:</label>
                <textarea name="issue" id="issue" required></textarea><br />
                <label style="font-weight: bold;">Unknowns About Issue:</label>
                <textarea name="unknowns" id="unknowns"></textarea><br />
                <label style="font-weight: bold;">People Involved in CTA:</label>
                <textarea name="people" id="people"></textarea>
                <!-- Assign Main Contact -->
                <select name="lead" id="lead" data-iconpos="left" required>
                    <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
                    <option value="Dan">Dan</option>
                    <option value="Alex">Alex</option>
                    <option value="Brian">Brian</option>
                </select>
                <!-- End Main Contact -->
                <!-- Assign Viewers to the CTA -->
                <select multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" name="notify[]" id="notify" data-iconpos="left" required>
                    <option>Assign Viewers</option>
                    <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
                    <option value="Dan">Dan</option>
                    <option value="Alex">Alex</option>
                    <option value="Brian">Brian</option>
                </select>
                <!-- End Viewers -->
                <br /><br />
                <input type="hidden" name="doform" value="doform">
                <button name="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit CTA</button>

                <div id="message"></div>
            </form>

        </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

---EDIT Working jQuery code below
I ended up using a blend of deblocker's code mixed with mine and ended up with the following code. This does work like I expect now. So when I pick a name in lead select list it is graying out the option in the multiple select for the notify select list. Picking a different user will clear the previously selected and gray out just the one that is selected. Thanks deblocker again for the wonderful help!

```
$("#lead").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#notify option").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#notify option[value='"+value+"']").attr("disabled",true);
    $("#notify").selectmenu("refresh", true);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger change does affect the value, to disable an option you should refresh the widget. Try this:

```js
function toggleOptions() {
  var value = "Mark";
  if($("#select-custom option[value='"+value+"']").attr("disabled"))
    $("#select-custom option[value='"+value+"']").removeAttr("disabled")
  else
    $("#select-custom option[value='"+value+"']").attr("disabled","disabled");
  $("#select-custom").selectmenu("refresh", true);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
      <button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-mini" onclick="toggleOptions();">toggle Mark</button>
      <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="select-custom">Assign Viewers</label>
        <select name="select-custom" id="select-custom" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true">
          <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
          <option value="Dan">Dan</option>
          <option value="Alex">Alex</option>
          <option value="Brian">Brian</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks again deblocker I got it working with your removeAttr and selectmenu("refresh", true) code examples! Your a life saver.